# How to change analog clock widget on home screen to digital clock?

Tags: app-widgets, home-screen, clock

I have an analog clock widget on my home screen and I want to change it to a digital clock.

If I tap the widget it takes me inside the clock app. If I select settings and then select "Style Digital", the home screen clock is still an analog clock.

How to change the home screen analog clock to a digital clock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make the widget change from analogue to digital, but you can replace the analogue one from a digital one. Hold your finger on the clock widget and drag it to the delete icon to remove it. Then, to add a digital clock widget, go to the app drawer and click **Widgets**, and find **Digital clock** in the list. Hold your finger on the digital clock to pick it up, and drag it where you like on the home screen.

Answer (score 1):

On later versions, swiping your finger vertically across the circle will cause it to flip over. On one side is analogue, the other is digital.